# how to override jQuery validation two times?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, validation

I have a validation using jQuery.
I kind of override it first time already using what's provided in the document by doing something like

```
        $('#userDetailForm').validate({
            // Set validations for specific fields
            rules: {
                profile_image: {
                    required: true
                },
```

Please ignore about my closing tags

This is actually a profile picture upload.  The first time, the user MUST have the a picture.  I am using the same page that if an image exist then the image will show.

But the thing is, after the image is shown, it is an option for user to upload a new picture but with the jQuery validation it forces user to upload an image again.

let's say I have this in my html

```
    <input type="file" name="profile_image" id="image">
```

then the above where I wrote the `rule` as `required: true`

when page loads, there will be an image then in html there will be an `img` element shown.

I thought I can overwrite the rules again by adding something like

```
            if ($('body').find('img').length) {
                $('#userDetailForm').validate({
                    // Set validations for specific fields
                    rules: {
                        profile_image: {
                            required: false
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
```

but this doesn't work at all.

Does anyone know how I can make the required go away if an image exist?

Comment: You could set a variable to `true` or `false` depending on whether a profile picture exists and then use that variable as the value for `required`.

Comment: @ConnorGurney omg that's a smart move! thx thx a lot!!!

Comment: No problem. :) I turned my comment to an answer so if it works, please mark it as correct down below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set a variable to `true` or `false` depending on whether a profile picture exists and then use that variable as the value for `required`.